# Is the shred utility effective when run in WSL2 for securely deleting files in windows NTFS partitions?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, coreutils

I want to securely delete a file in a Windows NTFS partition from WSL2

The file can be accessed in WSL from `/mnt/c/path_to_file`

will using `shred /mnt/c/path_to_file` actually perform a secure erase given the constraints of WSL?

Trying the command does garble the contents of the file but I'm unsure if it's actually effective.

P.S. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 [WSL2] on Windows 10 build 2004

Comment: There are zillions of such Windows utilities, so what's the point?

Comment: WSL has had full access to user's files within Windows environment for several Windows versions at this point. If you delete a files within WSL that exists in a user's directory, the file is actually deleted.